# How useful is it to know the ground state energy of an arbitrary $k$-local Hamiltonian, if Nature herself can never find such energy?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, applications, qma

We know that the $2$-local Hamiltonian problem is (promise) QMA-complete, which under the reasonable assumption that BQP$\subsetneq$QMA implies that no fast quantum algorithm exists to determine the eigenstate, much less the energy, of the ground state of such a Hamiltonian.

An implication is that not even Nature herself can find the ground state of such a Hamiltonian, as it might take longer than the age of the universe to settle into such a state (or even to learn said energy).

**But if Nature could never find the entangled ground state of our Hamiltonian, how much value is there in the ground state itself?**

For example, would knowing the ground state of, say, some lump of metal for some hard, bespoke Hamiltonian help us in constructing a room-temperature superconductor, or help us achieve fusion or otherwise be of significant relevance?

---

This is contrasted with the classical case, wherein even knowing whether solutions to certain satisfiability problems exists would be of extreme industrial significance - even though we can similarly conclude, assuming that P$\subsetneq$NP and [SETH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) etc., that a classical computer could take longer than the age of the universe to determine the existence of a solution.

Also, NP$\subseteq$QMA, so if our Hamiltonian just describes a classical NP problem then yes knowing the ground energy lets us solve the corresponding NP problem, but if the ground state were some highly-entangled eigenstate then is such a state still valuable if Nature cannot find it?

Comment: Shall we believe the Nature is a computer-like agent, or it just behaves as it is? A task with formidable complexity doesn't mean it cannot exist in the nature. It might take thousand of years for a modern computer to simulate a porcelain cup shattered on the ground, but only take one second to drop the cup at your hand and observe what will happen then.

Comment: Thanks @Yunzhe - your comment reminds me of Borchard's criticism in his [teacup argument](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=sFhhQRxWTIM). But I think your implication is in the opposite direction of where I was going.  Assuming a quantum computer can efficiently simulate any local Hamiltonian thrown its way, this would include any lobbed up by Nature.  Contrapositively if a quantum computer cannot efficiently find the ground state of such a Hamiltonian, then surely Nature cannot either.

Comment: 1. We model physical phenomena with "simple" Hamiltonians. The real universe is known to be very complicated when you don't neglect all the terms (see the standard model Lagrangian). Usually you always have some long-range interaction somewhere.
2. We still have not solved how gravity interacts with the quantum world, o we don't really know what nature exactly is doing.
3. It is not that everything should be easy to compute in nature. Nature can solve very difficult interactions and differential equations in an instant where we can't. Hence, you shouldn't compare our computation power to it.

Comment: Thanks @D.A.!  I'm mostly on board with 1 and 2 - but I get off the train at 3. There's a difference between what Nature does in an instant for a particular problem of a particular size, and how long Nature takes to do things when the size of the problem gets bigger and bigger - this much was appreciated by Feynman in his '82 (and '86) papers. It is absolutely appropriate for me to compare the computational power of a quantum computer to what Nature herself does - this was the *original motivation* of Feynman. This (among other reasons) is why we want a quantum computer in the first place.